# Unity(C#) - Как проверить, является ли объект землёй?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть объект "Player", и есть объекты земли, которые имеют скрипт "grass". Как осуществить проверку, соприкосается ли объект "Player" с землёй в данный момент?

Comment: можно попробовать по тегу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации подобного есть готовые механизмы:

1. [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) и [`OnTriggerExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html):

   ```
   public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
       void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
           // начало столкновения
       }
   }

   void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
           // окончание столкновения
   }
   ```

В `OnTriggerEnter` вы ловите все столкновения с другими объектами. Вы можете сохранять эти объекты в список, а в `OnTriggerExit` удалять. Тогда для осуществления проверки, соприкасается ли ваш объект с чем-то конкретным, вам достаточно посмотреть этот список.

2. Топорное решение с [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). Самим рейкастить периодически, скажем, вниз. Смотреть, есть ли пересечение с чем-то. Если да, то смотреть, что это за объект.
3. Есть ещё [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html). Можно получить список коллайдеров, с которыми сфера пересекается.

Comment: Я пробовал делать с OnTriggerEnter, но он проверяет объекты, которые "вошли" в игрока. Как проверять, допустим в каком-то небольшом радиусе от игрока разные коллайдеры?

Comment: @Артём https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую